# Writing a vector sum in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, grid, interpolation

Suppose I have a function `phi(x1,x2)=k1*x1+k2*x2` which I have evaluated over a grid where the grid is a square having boundaries at -100 and 100 in both `x1` and `x2` axis with some step size say `h=0.1`. Now I want to calculate this sum over the grid with which I'm struggling:

[image]

What I was trying :

```matlab
clear all
close all
clc
D=1; h=0.1;
D1 = -100;
D2 = 100;
X = D1 : h : D2;
Y = D1 : h : D2;
[x1, x2] = meshgrid(X, Y);
k1=2;k2=2;
phi = k1.*x1 + k2.*x2;
figure(1)
surf(X,Y,phi)
m1=-500:500;
m2=-500:500;
[M1,M2,X1,X2]=ndgrid(m1,m2,X,Y)
sys=@(m1,m2,X,Y) (k1*h*m1+k2*h*m2).*exp((-([X Y]-h*[m1 m2]).^2)./(h^2*D))
sum1=sum(sys(M1,M2,X1,X2))
```

Matlab says error in `ndgrid`, any idea how I should code this?

MATLAB shows:

```
Error using repmat
Requested 10001x1001x2001x2001 (298649.5GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater
than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference
panel for more information.

Error in ndgrid (line 72)
        varargout{i} = repmat(x,s);

Error in new_try1 (line 16)
[M1,M2,X1,X2]=ndgrid(m1,m2,X,Y)
```

Comment: That error message is incomplete, please paste the complete error message.

Comment: the error says that you will be out of RAM (apparently you have less than 29891.8GB available;) ). This is due to the matrix calculation that you want to do. | BTW, please structure your code better next time. & strip it to the essential parts

Comment: Thanks for the the reply, is the code all right or have I done something wrong? What else can be done then?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact and complete wording of the error message

Comment: Why are you using `syms` here? It looks like everything in the problem is numeric rather than symbolic... This comes after your error, but it shows that your approach isn't well defined. Try including a [mcve] in your question, emphasis on **minimal**, such as a much smaller input grid where you can show the expected outputs using hand calcs so we can validate any proposed solution!

Comment: @Daniel , Sardar Usama, done !

Comment: @Wolfie yes maybe that's the reason, then how would i proceed ? i don't understand

Comment: @Wolfie, there is no symbolic calculation here, have you missread the name of the anonymous function `sys` ?

Comment: If you have an infinite sum, have you considered to use an integral ?

Comment: @obchardon no, how can I do that?

Comment: @obchardon My bad, tired eyes. Please ignore the first part of my comment - the request for a simpler example with expected outputs still stands!

Comment: Some things are not worth (or possible) to vectorize. Why don’t you write a loop over `x1` and `x2`?

Comment: You have an infinite sum with `m ∈ (-inf,inf)`, since an integrale is the limit of a sum, you can integrate your function `M`, something like `integral(M*dm)` ( the integral of `M` over the variable `m` from -inf to inf). Once you got the result you can now compute the value for each `x1` and `x2`.

Comment: @obchardon okay this makes sense but i'm pretty bad with matlab i'm not sure about coding this up, will try this, but will appreciate if you can show me this (if possible) for once so that i can learn from it , sorry.

Comment: The error message is still incomplete. Please update your question and include the complete error message!

Comment: Besides the memory issues, 1. m_2 is not defined, should be m2
2. `e.^` is not supported by matlab, in MATLAB you use `exp()`
3. You are using `*` to multiply matrices.

Comment: @Daniel yes fixed, and edited.

Comment: @Daniel, if i make ```D1=-10, D2=10, m1=-10:10; m2=-10:10; ``` to get rid of memory fault , i'm getting an error message : ```Array dimensions must match for binary array op``` and ```Error in new_try1>@(m1,m2,X,Y)(k1*h*m1+k2*h*m2).*exp((-([X,Y]-h*[m1,m2]).^2)./(h^2*D)) (line 17)
sys=@(m1,m2,X,Y) (k1*h*m1+k2*h*m2).*exp((-([X Y]-h*[m1 m2]).^2)./(h^2*D));``` Which indicates i'm doing something wrong while writing the sum ?

Comment: Please [edit] your original post to include the details. Your above commment is not legible

Comment: @SardarUsama i've edited it.

Comment: No, you haven't

Comment: @SardarUsama i think i've added everything to my knowledge and what daniel said, where did i miss ?

Comment: Your comment that starts with: @.Daniel, if I make `D1=-10, D2=10,....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your comments and your code, it appears as though you don't fully understand what the equation is asking you to compute.

To obtain the value M(x1,x2) at some given (x1,x2), you have to compute that sum over Z2. Of course, using a numerical toolbox such as MATLAB, you could only ever hope to compute over some finite range of Z2. In this case, since (x1,x2) covers the range [-100,100] x [-100,100], and h=0.1, it follows that mh covers the range [-1000, 1000] x [-1000, 1000]. Example: m = (-1000, -1000) gives you mh = (-100, -100), which is the bottom-left corner of your domain. So really, phi(mh) is just phi(x1,x2) evaluated on all of your discretised points.

As an aside, since you need to compute `|x-hm|^2`, you can treat `x = x1 + i x2` as a complex number to make use of MATLAB's `abs` function. If you were strictly working with vectors, you would have to use `norm`, which is OK too, but a bit more verbose. Thus, for some given `x=(x10, x20)`, you would compute `x-hm` over the entire discretised plane as `(x10 - x1) + i (x20 - x2)`.

Finally, you can compute 1 term of M at a time:

```
D=1; h=0.1;
D1 = -100;
D2 = 100;
X = (D1 : h : D2); % X is in rows (dim 2)
Y = (D1 : h : D2)'; % Y is in columns (dim 1)
k1=2;k2=2;
phi = k1*X + k2*Y;

M = zeros(length(Y), length(X));

for j = 1:length(X)
    for i = 1:length(Y)
        % treat (x - hm) as a complex number
        x_hm = (X(j)-X) + 1i*(Y(i)-Y); % this computes x-hm for all m
        M(i,j) = 1/(pi*D) * sum(sum(phi .* exp(-abs(x_hm).^2/(h^2*D)), 1), 2);
    end
end
```

By the way, this computation takes quite a long time. You can consider either increasing `h`, reducing `D1` and `D2`, or changing all three of them.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine and makes sense. I think the question asks me to evaluate phi on a grid and inperpolated for all m in Z^2, where I think M_{h, D} is the interpolant. This summation seems to give a good result for large D. I will edit the question for more clarity.